# PHP - Login Form does not show

Tags: php, html, mysql

My Login form does not show. I am getting a blank page.

So please post the correct code, so I can replace it easily.
I am new to php, so my code will not be super professional as yours.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv=""Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Member Register</title>
</head>
<body><?php
    $form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>

               <table>
                 <tr>
                   <td>Username:</td>
                   <td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>Password:</td>
                   <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td></td>
                   <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login' /></td>
                 </tr>
               </table>
             </form>";

    if ($_POST['loginbtn']) {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if ($user) {
            if ($password) {

                require("connect.php");

                $password = md5(md5("Ji5t63s".password."v5h2ih47");

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if ($numrows == 1) {
                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                    $dbid = $row['id'];
                    $dbuser = $row['username'];
                    $dbpass = $row['password'];
                    $dbactive = $row['active'];

                    if ($password == $dbpass){
                        if ($dbactive == 1){
                            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;

                            echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b>. <a href="./member.php">Click here</a> to go to the member page.";

                        }
                        else
                            echo "you must activate your account to login. $form";
                    }
                    else
                        echo "you did not entered a correct password. $form";
                }
                else
                    echo "The user you entered was not found. $form";
                    mysql_close();

            }
            else
                echo "You must enter you password. $form";
        }
        else
            echo "You must enter your username. $form";
    }
    else
        echo $form;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can not set session variable in the middle of the html!!!!! you have to do that before html. That is why you are getting blank page! put ini_set("display_errors",1); before session_start and you will see.

Comment: Instead of implementing a self invented (and in your case very unsafe) password hashing scheme, you should have a look at PHP's function [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Those functions are not only easier to use, they will make password handling really safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(tested)**

The reason why your form is not showing is because of these two lines:

**1)** This one had a missing closing parentheses `)` at the end.

```
$password = md5(md5("Ji5t63s".password."v5h2ih47");
```

Should be:

```
$password = md5(md5("Ji5t63s".password."v5h2ih47"));
```

**2)** The `<a href="./member.php">` - Problem is the (unescaped) double quotes or use of single quotes.

Your existing line:

```
echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b>. <a href="./member.php">Click here</a> to go to the member page.";
```

Should be:

```
echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b>. <a href='./member.php'>Click here</a> to go to the member page.";
```

or escape them with `\"`

```
echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b>. <a href=\"./member.php\">Click here</a> to go to the member page.";
```

Now as far as the functionality of the rest (of code with include files), that is out of my hands. You asked why your form was not showing up.

Comment: hey but you also have seen that the PHP code for the login system doesnt work either. so can you help me with that to??

Comment: @WireCoder I can try. What exactly is not working?

Comment: when i fill in the fields correctly ist not gonna show the echo you logged in as. but it just refreshes the form

Comment: @WireCoder If you're running the entire code in the same page, try using `<form action='' method='post'>` instead of `<form action='./login.php' method='post'>` - I'm assuming that your present code's page (filename) is called `login.php`?

Comment: yea it is but now it says incorrect password but i am realy filling in the correct username and password

Comment: @WireCoder It's hard to say. Your password method seems to be a bit out of the ordinary. Did it work before?

Comment: no  it didt work before this is the 1e time i made something like this.

Comment: @WireCoder The password needs to match the `md5` password in the database how it was initially set.

Comment: thanks for your help i had my password encrypted in a md5 hash but i think the login system couldnt decryptmy password

Answer (score -2):

Please don't have any whitespace characters before your `session_start()` .

Instead of:

```
    <?php
session_start(); ?>
```

please make it:

```
<?php
session_start();?>
```

The session needs to be started before you output anything to the browser. Please remember PHP is an interpreter, and therefore is executed by each line.

Comment: Don't make suggestions without testing first.

Comment: It would have been difficult to test it as it needs DB connections, etc.
Posted the first bug which I found in the code.